# Can a paper directly be written on a new application developed rather then an algorithm from existing research results or algorithms?

Tags: research-process, independent-researcher

Suppose we design a prototype for a new product that is indeed novel.

Would writing a paper on such a thing be useful as mostly the papers talk about new algorithms or their upgrades or some new theory ?

I am talking about just a new product that does something better than the existing ones but uses old algorithms and research.

Comment: Useful to whom?

Comment: @JeffE Depends upon the application like it could be for business analytics, advertising etc.

Answer (score 5):

This is something that I have been doing.  If I understand your question correctly, you are looking at a new product using existing algorithms and techniques. If this is the case, the answer is yes: many journals will welcome this, as I have found.  I have also taken an existing technology, aspects of existing algorithms, based on existing research and developed a brand new technique.

A couple of caveats though:

- You will need to make the specific context to which it will be used crystal clear, this must be the focus.
- You must give full credit for the prior information and techniques.
- You must fully justify why such an altered technique is useful, what are the implications and benefits of such a product.

Comment: If such journals are there then it is good. The only issue would be to find such journals. I will have to search such journals.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you are finding a new (and maybe promising) *application* to an existing technique **X**. If that's the case then yes. You are showing a new perspective of **X** applicability to real domains.

This is specially important when the applicability of **X** is questionable (i.e. **X** literature lacks real applications for it), then definitely this seems strong findings.